# Search for value inside an array in a jsonb

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

If I have a jsonb object like this:

```
{
  "eligibility": true,
  "dates_of_births": [
    [
      "2010-08-12",
      {
        "last_name": "abcd",
        "first_name": "efgh"
      }
    ],
    [
      "2009-08-12",
      {
        "last_name": "xyz",
        "first_name": "str"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

How can I query for anyone with the a specific first name or dob? Essentially how can I search for values inside an

Thanks for the help. I'm sorry for the terrible object structure, but it was set much before I started work on this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join your table to the set coming from `jsonb_array_elements(jsdata->'dates_of_births')`, and then filter out the desired name or date of birth through use of `@>` operator, *which looks whether the left JSON value contain the right JSON path/value entries at the top level*,

and add `->>` operators in order to extract the corresponding values for the keys or indexes in the SELECT-list such as :

```
SELECT j.value ->> 0 AS "DOB", 
      (j.value ->> 1)::jsonb ->> 'first_name' AS "First Name",
      (j.value ->> 1)::jsonb ->> 'last_name' AS "Last Name"
  FROM t
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsdata->'dates_of_births') AS j 
 WHERE j @> '[{"first_name": "efgh"}]'::jsonb
```

**OR**

```
SELECT j.value ->> 0 AS "DOB", 
      (j.value ->> 1)::jsonb ->> 'first_name' AS "First Name",
      (j.value ->> 1)::jsonb ->> 'last_name' AS "Last Name"
  FROM t
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(jsdata->'dates_of_births') AS j 
 WHERE j @> '["2009-08-12"]'::jsonb
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=54ab1646762380e36a2b7bdbe50b78ea)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. Finally got around to implementing it and it worked perfectly!

Comment: you're wlcome @fractal5 :)